# additional filters on binding with existing aggregation

Tags: javascript, filter, sapui5, aggregation

I have a value help dialog with a table whose rows are bound like this:

```
        // set data
        oValueHelpDialogTable.bindAggregation("rows", {
            path: "/ProductSet",
            filters: aFilters
        });
```

with filters that are applied to the oData source.

Now I want to set additional filters through a filter bar:

```
var bFilters = [];
bFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter(aKeys[0], sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oSearchField.getValue()));
var oTableBinding = oValueHelpDialogTable.getBinding();
oTableBinding.filter(bFilters);
```

But for some reason the filters are not applied. If I remove aFilters from the bindAggregation call the additional filters work.

Comment: You are replacing the filters, not adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I.B.N. says, you are replacing your filters, no adding a new one...

My recommendation is to save the current status of the filters in a global variable in your controller or in a "view model"

Then just retrieve them before pushing the new filter and setting them again.

If you use a view model, it would be something like this

```
//To save the current filters
this.getView().getModel("myViewModelName").setProperty("/currentFilters", aFilters)

//To retrieve the current filters
var bFilters = this.getView().getModel("myViewModelName").getProperty("/currentFilters")
bFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter(aKeys[0], sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, oSearchField.getValue()));
var oTableBinding = oValueHelpDialogTable.getBinding();
oTableBinding.filter(bFilters);
```